# Is there a 2 word expression to describe someone who's fluent in a language?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, grammaticality

For instance someone who's fluent in Korean would be called a Korean fluent.
How correct is this expression?

Comment: (Edited Comment) The OED lists three meanings of the noun 'fluent' but they do not relate to language, rather to the 'flowing' concept.

Comment: I don't know where we'd call someone Korean fluent.  It may be fluent but it's not idiomatic.  Fluent in Korean is idiomatic.

Comment: It needs to be hyphenated, as "Korean-fluent", if you're going to use it this way. Still doesn't sound too nice though.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "language XYZ proficient". So, someone who is fluent in English can be called "English proficient". Someone who is proficient and/or fluent in Spanish, for example, can be called "Spanish proficient".